# How to install alien arena 7.52

Tags: games

I downloaded the tar.gz file from the site, but it seems kind of confusing.  Is there any easier way to install the newest version?

Answer (score 2):

Is there much difference between 7.51 (which is in Oneiric repositories) and 7.52? You can install 7.51-3 just by typing

```
sudo apt-get install alien-arena
```

or from Software Center

Comment: I tried this before too, but it won't even start when I click on it.  and yes, its a big update

Comment: I could just do it from playdeb, but it's 7.51 and I'd prefer to have it updated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all extract by right-clicking on the downloaded file and move to extract to that and run the following commands at terminal:

1. cd Downloads and press ENTER key.
2. cd ./[Type the downloaded folder filename after extract here] and press ENTER key
3. Type ./configure and press ENTER
4. Type make and press ENTER
5. Type  make install and press ENTER

Comment: it isn't a deb. It's a tarball.